# Angular - How to compose data in reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a http post service that wants a date with time in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
```

In one form now I have a formGroup like this:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [''],
  startDate: [null],
})
```

but in the form I have three input:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
 <mat-datepicker formControlName="day?"></mat-datepicker>
 <input type="number" formControlName="hour?">
 <input type="number" formcontrolName="minutes?">
<form>
```

I have a datepicker for select a date, and two inputs for managing hour and minutes. My idea is to convert the formGroup in this way:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   name: [''],
   day: [null],
   hour: [null],
   minutes: [null]
})
```

But the server needs only one field and I would have a clean way to do it...my idea was to create single fields for managing each value and in the submit compose the data in someway or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Personally - I'd go with creating a separate component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor` (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)). It would contain your three inputs, but would work as a single form control (i.e. emitted when any "child" input emits). Then, your form would retain it's "correct" format:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [''],
  startDate: [null],
})
```

And your template would look something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
 <app-custom-date-picker formControlName="startDate"></app-custom-date-picker>
<form>
```

I think that would be the most "clean" approach and would allow you to re-use that component across multiple other forms if needed be.

I won't go into the details of how to create your custom form control (i.e. implement `ControlValueAccessor` as this is covered by multiple greate guides around the web.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Angular Material Datepicker. It works really well with `formBuilder`: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Check this, stackblitz, where I fill a `mat-datepicker` with `newDate = new Date();`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyxsqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts